# Remove Current Item from List if some criteria matches

Tags: vb.net, list

I am trying to remove my current item in for each loop if some criterai matches but its triggering error after removing and looping again.

My sample code:

```
        For Each Item As BookingRoom In myBookedRooms
            If Item.RoomInfo.UIN = myRoom.UIN Then
                myBookedRooms.Remove(Item)
                Continue For
            End If
        Next
```

***Note RoomInfo and myRoom are both instances of Room Class**

I am using `myBookedRooms.remove` but its trigerring error so what can be the correct way for doing it? ie, remove booked room if the room id matches with selected one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're modifying the collection while iterating over it.

You can iterate the list in reverse with a for loop:

```
For i = myBookedRooms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If myBookedRooms(i).RoomInfo.UIN = myRoom.UIN Then
        myBookedRooms.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Alternately, you can use the [`RemoveAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
myBookedRooms.RemoveAll(Function(item) item.RoomInfo.UIN = myRoom.UIN)
```

Another option is to use the [`Enumerable.Where` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to filter the results, but unlike the previous two approaches you would need to reverse your logic check to exclude the matching items since the intention is to remove them:

```
myBookedRooms = myBookedRooms
                    .Where(Function(item) item.RoomInfo.UIN <> myRoom.UIN)
                    .ToList()
```

Comment: @Joel did you mean `Where`? `Except` would require a second sequence. Updated to include `Where`.